# Acumatica: Ability to override DefaultEndpointImpl to add advanced custom logic to contract REST API

Tags: c#, rest, api, acumatica

I'm wondering if it possible to override DefaultEndpointImpl.cs or add my own API logic in another file?

I'm struggling with a few API calls which require the logic in this file to be overridden or added to. For example I am able to create a purchase receipt for a PO via the api successfully, however I'm not able to add a "Transfer Receipt"  purchase receipt in the same way.

I've included various non-standard fields to the API endpoints that reference the original transfer, transfer order and shipment but have been unsuccessful. The API calls succeeds but no lines are added. I've been able to get lines to update their quantity once generated but can't add or delete current lines.

The problem looks to stem from this code, which seems to add functionality that correctly handles adding Purchase order lines logic of the graph but doesn't do anything special for other receipt types.

```
[FieldsProcessed(new[] { "POLineNbr", "POOrderType", "POOrderNbr" })]
protected void PurchaseReceiptDetail_Insert(PXGraph graph, EntityImpl entity, EntityImpl targetEntity) {

    var receiptEntry = (POReceiptEntry)graph;

    var lineNbr = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "POLineNbr") as EntityValueField;
    var orderType = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "POOrderType") as EntityValueField;
    var orderNbr = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "POOrderNbr") as EntityValueField;

    bool insertViaAddPO = lineNbr != null && orderNbr != null && orderType != null;

    if (!insertViaAddPO && (lineNbr != null || orderType != null || orderNbr != null)) {

        throw new PXException(PO.Messages.POTypeNbrLineNbrMustBeFilled);
    }

    var detailsCache = receiptEntry.transactions.Cache;

    if (insertViaAddPO) {

        receiptEntry.filter.Cache.Remove(receiptEntry.filter.Current);
        receiptEntry.filter.Cache.Insert(new POReceiptEntry.POOrderFilter());

        var filter = receiptEntry.filter.Current; var state = receiptEntry.filter.Cache.GetStateExt(filter, "OrderType") as PXStringState;

        if (state != null && state.AllowedLabels.Contains(orderType.Value)) {
            orderType.Value = state.ValueLabelDic.Single(p => p.Value == orderType.Value).Key;

        }

        receiptEntry.filter.Cache.SetValueExt(filter, "OrderType", orderType.Value);
        receiptEntry.filter.Cache.SetValueExt(filter, "OrderNbr", orderNbr.Value);
        receiptEntry.filter.Update(filter);

        var orders = receiptEntry.poLinesSelection.Select().Select(r => r.GetItem<POReceiptEntry.POLineS>());
        var order = orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.LineNbr == int.Parse(lineNbr.Value));

        if (order == null) {
            throw new PXException(PO.Messages.PurchaseOrderLineNotFound);
        }

        order.Selected = true;

        receiptEntry.poLinesSelection.Update(order);
        receiptEntry.Actions["AddPOOrderLine2"].Press();

    } else {
        detailsCache.Current = detailsCache.Insert();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I have managed to get everything working as I need. However I'm concerned that since this is not documented information that it may be subject to change in the near future.

The methods in the class DefaultEndpointImpl are called via reflection. To add custom functionality for my default endpoint I have extended the default class and added the necessary attributes to my class and functions.

My custom class adds the following:

1. Overides the default PurchaseReceiptDetail_Insert function to add transfer receipt functionality.
2. Adds ReceiptDetail_Insert method to allow adding an IN receipt referencing

The first one was pretty straight forward and I'm happy with the outcome. The second one took a lot of time and debugging to get right, is hacky and probably doesn't work with serial tracked items. The reason it's taken so long is because there are many unknowns and I've essentially been guessing based on the code in the base class. For example I'm not even sure at which stage this function fires. It looks the functions  completely override some other default logic which is invisible.

So take it or leave it! Maybe I will reach out to Acumatica to see if I can get more information.

```
using PX.Api; 
using PX.Api.ContractBased; 
using PX.Api.ContractBased.Models; 
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CS;

namespace AcuStock
{
  [PXVersion("5.30.001", "AcuStock")]  
  [PXVersion("6.00.001", "AcuStock")]  
  [PXVersion("17.200.001", "AcuStock")]  
  public class AcuStockEndpointImpl : PX.Objects.DefaultEndpointImpl
  {

    [FieldsProcessed(new[] { "POLineNbr", "POOrderType", "POOrderNbr", "OrigLineNbr", "OrigRefNbr" })]
    protected new void PurchaseReceiptDetail_Insert(PXGraph graph, EntityImpl entity, EntityImpl targetEntity){

        var lineNbr = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "OrigLineNbr") as EntityValueField;
        var refNbr = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "OrigRefNbr") as EntityValueField;
        var receiptQty = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "ReceiptQty") as EntityValueField;
        var location = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Location") as EntityValueField;
        var inventoryID = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "InventoryID") as EntityValueField;

        bool insertViaAddTR = lineNbr != null && refNbr != null;

        var receiptEntry = (POReceiptEntry) graph;

        if (insertViaAddTR){

            receiptEntry.addReceipt.Cache.Remove(receiptEntry.addReceipt.Current);
            receiptEntry.addReceipt.Cache.Insert(new POReceiptEntry.POReceiptLineS());

            var filter = receiptEntry.addReceipt.Current;

            receiptEntry.addReceipt.Cache.SetValueExt(filter, "OrigRefNbr", refNbr.Value);
            receiptEntry.addReceipt.Cache.SetValueExt(filter, "OrigLineNbr", lineNbr.Value);
            receiptEntry.addReceipt.Cache.SetValueExt(filter, "InventoryID", inventoryID.Value);
            receiptEntry.addReceipt.Cache.SetValueExt(filter, "ReceiptQty", receiptQty.Value);
            if (location != null)
                receiptEntry.addReceipt.Cache.SetValueExt(filter, "LocationID", location.Value);
            receiptEntry.addReceipt.Update(filter);

            var lines = receiptEntry.addReceipt.Select().Select(r => r.GetItem<POReceiptEntry.POReceiptLineS>());
            var line = lines.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrigLineNbr == int.Parse(lineNbr.Value));

            if (line == null){
                throw new PXException(PX.Objects.PO.Messages.PurchaseOrderLineNotFound);
            }

            receiptEntry.addPOReceiptLine2.Press();

        } else {
            base.PurchaseReceiptDetail_Insert(graph, entity, targetEntity);
        }

        var allocations = (targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => string.Equals(f.Name, "Allocations")) as EntityListField).Value ?? new EntityImpl[0];

        if (allocations.Any(a => a.Fields != null && a.Fields.Length > 0)){
            // Remove automatically added allocation
            if (receiptEntry.splits.Current != null){
                receiptEntry.splits.Delete(receiptEntry.splits.Current);
            }
    }

    }

    [FieldsProcessed(new[] { "OrigLineNbr", "OrigRefNbr", "Quantity", "Location" })]
    protected void ReceiptDetails_Insert(PXGraph graph, EntityImpl entity, EntityImpl targetEntity) {

        var lineNbr = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "OrigLineNbr") as EntityValueField;
        var receiptQty = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Quantity") as EntityValueField;
        var location = targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Location") as EntityValueField;

        var allocations = (targetEntity.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => string.Equals(f.Name, "Allocations")) as EntityListField).Value ?? new EntityImpl[0];
        var hasAllocations = allocations.Any(a => a.Fields != null && a.Fields.Length > 0);

        var receiptEntry = (INReceiptEntry) graph;

        string transferNbr = receiptEntry.receipt.Current.TransferNbr;

        var detailsCache = receiptEntry.transactions.Cache;

        if (lineNbr == null || transferNbr == null){

            detailsCache.Current = detailsCache.Insert();
            return;
        }

        INTran newtran = null;
        decimal newtranqty = Decimal.Parse(receiptQty.Value);
        decimal newtrancost = 0m;
        receiptEntry.ParseSubItemSegKeys();

        using (new PXReadBranchRestrictedScope())
        {
            foreach (PXResult<INTransitLine, INLocationStatus2, INTransitLineLotSerialStatus, INSite, InventoryItem, INTran> res in
                PXSelectJoin<INTransitLine,
                InnerJoin<INLocationStatus2, On<INLocationStatus2.locationID, Equal<INTransitLine.costSiteID>>,
                LeftJoin<INTransitLineLotSerialStatus,
                        On<INTransitLine.transferNbr, Equal<INTransitLineLotSerialStatus.transferNbr>,
                        And<INTransitLine.transferLineNbr, Equal<INTransitLineLotSerialStatus.transferLineNbr>>>,
                InnerJoin<INSite, On<INSite.siteID, Equal<INTransitLine.toSiteID>>,
                InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<INLocationStatus2.inventoryID>>,
                InnerJoin<INTran,
                    On<INTran.docType, Equal<INDocType.transfer>,
                    And<INTran.refNbr, Equal<INTransitLine.transferNbr>,
                    And<INTran.lineNbr, Equal<INTransitLine.transferLineNbr>,
                    And<INTran.invtMult, Equal<shortMinus1>>>>>>>>>>,
                Where<INTransitLine.transferNbr, Equal<Required<INTransitLine.transferNbr>>, And<INTransitLine.transferLineNbr, Equal<Required<INTransitLine.transferLineNbr>>>>,
                OrderBy<Asc<INTransitLine.transferNbr, Asc<INTransitLine.transferLineNbr>>>>
                .Select(receiptEntry, transferNbr, lineNbr.Value))
            {
                INTransitLine transitline = res;
                INLocationStatus2 stat = res;
                INTransitLineLotSerialStatus lotstat = res;
                INSite site = res;
                InventoryItem item = res;
                INTran tran = res; 

                if (stat.QtyOnHand == 0m || (lotstat != null && lotstat.QtyOnHand == 0m))
                    continue;

                if (newtran == null) { 

                    if (!object.Equals(receiptEntry.receipt.Current.BranchID, site.BranchID))
                    {
                        INRegister copy = PXCache<INRegister>.CreateCopy(receiptEntry.receipt.Current);
                        copy.BranchID = site.BranchID;
                        receiptEntry.receipt.Update(copy);
                    }

                    newtran = PXCache<INTran>.CreateCopy(tran);
                    newtran.OrigBranchID = newtran.BranchID;
                    newtran.OrigTranType = newtran.TranType;
                    newtran.OrigRefNbr = transitline.TransferNbr;
                    newtran.OrigLineNbr = transitline.TransferLineNbr;
                    newtran.BranchID = site.BranchID;
                    newtran.DocType = receiptEntry.receipt.Current.DocType;
                    newtran.RefNbr = receiptEntry.receipt.Current.RefNbr;
                    newtran.LineNbr = (int)PXLineNbrAttribute.NewLineNbr<INTran.lineNbr>(receiptEntry.transactions.Cache, receiptEntry.receipt.Current);
                    newtran.InvtMult = (short)1;
                    newtran.SiteID = transitline.ToSiteID;
                    newtran.LocationID = transitline.ToLocationID;
                    newtran.ToSiteID = null;
                    newtran.ToLocationID = null;
                    newtran.BaseQty = 0m;
                    newtran.Qty = 0m;
                    newtran.UnitCost = 0m;
                    newtran.Released = false;
                    newtran.InvtAcctID = null;
                    newtran.InvtSubID = null;
                    newtran.ReasonCode = null;
                    newtran.ARDocType = null;
                    newtran.ARRefNbr = null;
                    newtran.ARLineNbr = null;
                    newtran.ProjectID = null;
                    newtran.TaskID = null;
                    newtran.CostCodeID = null;
                    newtran.TranCost = 0m;

                    receiptEntry.splits.Current = null;

                    newtran = receiptEntry.transactions.Insert(newtran);

                    receiptEntry.transactions.Current = newtran;

                    if (receiptEntry.splits.Current != null)
                    {
                        receiptEntry.splits.Delete(receiptEntry.splits.Current);
                    }
                }

                if (hasAllocations){

                    newtranqty = 0m;

                    foreach (var allocation in allocations) { 

                        var newsplitqty = allocation.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Quantity") as EntityValueField;
                        var newsplitlocation = allocation.Fields.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Location") as EntityValueField;

                        INTranSplit newsplit = this.addReceiptSplitLine(receiptEntry, stat, lotstat, transitline, newtran, item, Decimal.Parse(newsplitqty.Value), newsplitlocation.Value);

                        newtrancost += newsplit.BaseQty.Value * newsplit.UnitCost.Value;
                        newtranqty += newsplit.BaseQty.Value;
                    }

                    break;

                } else {

                    INTranSplit newsplit = this.addReceiptSplitLine(receiptEntry, stat, lotstat, transitline, tran, item, newtranqty, null);

                    newtrancost += newsplit.BaseQty.Value * newsplit.UnitCost.Value;
                    newtranqty += newsplit.BaseQty.Value;

                }

            }

            receiptEntry.UpdateTranCostQty(newtran, newtranqty, newtrancost);

        }

    }

    [FieldsProcessed(new[] { "OrigLineNbr" })]
    protected void ReceiptAllocations_Insert(PXGraph graph, EntityImpl entity, EntityImpl targetEntity) {
        // no-op
    }

    private INTranSplit addReceiptSplitLine(INReceiptEntry receiptEntry, INLocationStatus2 stat, INTransitLineLotSerialStatus lotstat, INTransitLine transitline, INTran tran, InventoryItem item, Decimal qty, string location){

        INTranSplit newsplit;
        decimal newsplitqty;
        if (lotstat.QtyOnHand == null)
        {
            newsplit = new INTranSplit();
            newsplit.InventoryID = stat.InventoryID;
            newsplit.IsStockItem = true;
            newsplit.FromSiteID = transitline.SiteID;
            newsplit.SubItemID = stat.SubItemID;
            newsplit.LotSerialNbr = null;
            newsplitqty = qty;
        }
        else
        {
            newsplit = new INTranSplit();
            newsplit.InventoryID = lotstat.InventoryID;
            newsplit.IsStockItem = true;
            newsplit.FromSiteID = lotstat.FromSiteID;
            newsplit.SubItemID = lotstat.SubItemID;
            newsplit.LotSerialNbr = lotstat.LotSerialNbr;
            newsplitqty = qty;
        }

        newsplit.DocType = receiptEntry.receipt.Current.DocType;
        newsplit.RefNbr = receiptEntry.receipt.Current.RefNbr;
        newsplit.LineNbr = tran.LineNbr;
        newsplit.SplitLineNbr = (int)PXLineNbrAttribute.NewLineNbr<INTranSplit.splitLineNbr>(receiptEntry.splits.Cache, receiptEntry.receipt.Current);

        newsplit.UnitCost = 0m;
        newsplit.InvtMult = (short)1;
        newsplit.SiteID = transitline.ToSiteID;
        newsplit.PlanID = null;
        newsplit.Released = false;
        newsplit.ProjectID = null;
        newsplit.TaskID = null;

        if (location == null) { 
            newsplit.LocationID = lotstat.ToLocationID ?? transitline.ToLocationID;
        } else { 
            receiptEntry.splits.SetValueExt<INTranSplit.locationID>(newsplit, location);
        }

        newsplit = receiptEntry.splits.Insert(newsplit);

        newsplit.MaxTransferBaseQty = newsplitqty;
        newsplit.BaseQty = newsplitqty;
        newsplit.Qty = newsplit.BaseQty.Value;

        receiptEntry.UpdateCostSubItemID(newsplit, item);

        receiptEntry.SetCostAttributes(tran, newsplit, item, tran.OrigRefNbr);
        newsplit.UnitCost = PXCurrencyAttribute.BaseRound(receiptEntry, newsplit.UnitCost);
        receiptEntry.splits.Update(newsplit);

        return newsplit;
    }

  }
}
```