# REST API - Calling Custom PXAction from Endpoint

Tags: acumatica

I want to call a PXAction from the endpoint, pass it a record (or set of records if possible), and then have it pass me back the records updated with some information.

I have the following Action in my graph (graph is really only to allow this single action to be accessed)

```
    public PXSelect<INCustItemPriceRecord> view;

    public PXAction<INCustItemPriceRecord> ItemPrice;
    [PXUIField]
    [PXButton]
    protected virtual IEnumerable itemPrice(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
          var contacts = new List<INCustItemPriceRecord>(adapter.Get().Cast<INCustItemPriceRecord>());
          foreach (INCustItemPriceRecord record in contacts)
          {
               // Do stuff to the record(s)
          }
          return contacts;
     }
```

My DAC INCustItemPriceRecord is 6 unbound fields of String, int, datetime etc, really not interested in saving anything to the database. Let me know if you want to see specifics

The page itself has no controls on it whatsoever except the PXAction Button and a Datasource/view

I created a new endpoint, mapping that action after referencing my empty page as a 'Top-level', and the endpoint validated properly

I make a POST to entity/$EndpointName$/$Version$/$TopLevel$/$Action$

Body:

```
{
  "entity" : 
          {
          "Record":
                  { 
                  "CustIDIn": { "value": 5555 },
                  "QuantityIn": { "value": 5 },
                  "PricingDateIn": { "value": "6/18/2000" },
                  "DiscountCodeIDOut": { "value": "" },
                  "DiscountPercOut": { "value": "" },
                  "NewUnitPriceOut": { "value": ""},
                  "SourceOut": { "value": "" }
            }
}
```

And the error I continually get, after editing my json structure multiple times is:

```
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSqlDatabaseProvider.ExecuteReaderInternal(IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSelectResult.PXSelectResultEnumerator.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXView.GetResult(Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, Boolean reverseOrder, Int32 topCount, PXSearchColumn[] sorts, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()\r\nClientConnectionId:ff8c7e17-be04-41e2-9895-500370052e80\r\nError Number:156,State:1,Class:15",
"exceptionType": "PX.Api.ContractBased.OutcomeEntityHasErrorsException",
"stackTrace": "   at System.Monads.ArgumentCheck.CheckNull[TSource](TSource source, Func`1 exceptionSource)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetOperationResult(EntityImpl entity, EntityExportContextBuilder entityExportContextBuilder, PXSYTable exportedKeys, List`1 errors) in C:\\Bld\\AC-FULL2018R27-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 467\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Invoke(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action, CbOperationContext operationContext) in C:\\Bld\\AC-FULL2018R27-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 735\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.InvokeImpl(EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action) in C:\\Bld\\AC-FULL2018R27-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\Soap\\SoapFacadeBase.cs:line 143\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.SoapFacade.PX.Api.ContractBased.IRestGate.Invoke(EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action) in C:\\Bld\\AC-FULL2018R27-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\SystemContracts\\V2\\SoapFacade.cs:line 52\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.InvokeAction(String objectName, String actionName, ActionInvocation invocation) in C:\\Bld\\AC-FULL2018R27-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\SystemContracts\\V2\\RestController.cs:line 133\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

Let me know if this is just not supported or if you see something (most likely) obviously wrong

Thanks

Comment: Just an FYI, when I send Just a GET to:
entity/$EndpointName$/$Version$/$TopLevel$ I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, PXSelect<> doesn't like selecting a non database bound table, use PXFilter<>

Now I am just trying to get the body of the POST to get into the action and back out again, is this possible?

Comment: To get parameters inside the Action event handler requires a web service adapter. The feature isn't well documented: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51747283/7376238

Comment: PXSelect can work with unbound DACs when a matching data view delegate is defined in the graph.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Comment: Good luck if you're going to develop a web service adapter. They are tricky to get right and could be deprecated in the future as they are undocumented. Here's another example that could help you if you go this route: https://pastebin.com/ffHTaSkj

Comment: Yeah, we decided against it.. dont want to create extra work for myself down the road when/if it deprecates, thanks anyway!